# My application works on a .swf but not .exe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My application works perfects when I open it in its .swf format, but some buttons don't work correctly when I open it in its .exe format. It doesn't work correctly in HTML as well.

This is the error that flash gives me when I publish:
Warning: No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: Windows Projector

I have tried to merge code, but it only removes the error and does not solve the problem?

Comment: Going to need a bit more information regarding your FLA project. Are you using shared libs that will have a dependency? What is encompassed within your project?

Comment: I am using graphics and music that are linked in the library

Comment: What about TFL? What version of Flash Pro? How about some screenshots of your project library and publish settings? Right now, there are too many variables to determine root cause.

Comment: This is likely related to usage of TLF fonts. TLF fonts are deprecated. What version of flash player are you targeting ?

Comment: How you are creating .exe?

Comment: Through the publish settings in flash

Comment: Can you try to create .exe from your swf? Open your swf, go to file->Create Projector.